# How to change the base URL in QuickBook PHP API?

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have successfully done to deal with sandbox using [consolibyte/quickbooks-php](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3) and also made the app a product. Now i have to change the base url in quickbook api. i don't know where should i change the url? kindly guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using this:

http://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Then all you have to do is switch OFF sandbox mode by changing this:

https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/config.php#L100

To:

`$IPP->sandbox(false);`